# android 4.3 BLE device getting auto disconnect after multiple connection attempts

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app with BLE features for Android and it works perfectly fine, except when I attempt to connect and disconnect the BLE device multiple times. After several successful attempts at connect/disconnect, the BLE device directly calls the disconnect function after random interval of time even though it gets connected first.

```
public boolean connect(final String address)
{

  if (mBtAdapter == null || address == null) {
       Log.v("Notification", "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
       return false;
   }

   // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
   //mBtDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBtDeviceAddress)&&
   if (deviceGatt.get(address) != null) {
       Log.v("Notification", "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
       if (deviceGatt.get(address).connect()) {
           mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
           Log.v("Notification","Connection State :" +mConnectionState);
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }

   final BluetoothDevice device = mBtAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
   pairedDevice = device;
   if (device == null) {
       Log.v("Notification", "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
       return false;
   }
   // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
   // parameter to false.
   BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this,false,this.mGattCallBack);

   deviceGatt.put(address,mBluetoothGatt);

   Log.v("Notification", "Trying to create a new connection.");
   Log.v("Notification","Size of device gatt "+deviceGatt.size());
   mBtDeviceAddress = address;
   mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
   return true;
}

public boolean disconnect(BluetoothDevice device) {

   if (mBtAdapter == null || deviceGatt.get(device.getAddress()) == null) {
       Log.v("Notification", "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
       return false;
   }
   //Log.v("Notification","Device Address : "+device.getAddress());
   deviceGatt.get(device.getAddress()).disconnect();
   //deviceGatt.get(device.getAddress()).close();
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: The problem is still persisting.. please help me out with this if possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work for you but I found that bluetoothGatt automatically disconnects after about 4-7 minutes if no notification or characteristic write is called. The problem fixed for me by calling BluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi() every 5 seconds.

```
@Override
public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt,int rssi, int status){
    if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS)     
        System.out.println("onReadRemoteRssi: " + rssi);

    if (mBluetoothGatt != null) 
        myHandler.postDelayed(runnableReadRssi, 5000);
}
```

You should also make sure you close each bluetoothGatt and set to null after you don't need it anymore. I've read that if you have more than 5 bluetoothGatts active, you'll get an error about not being able to connect to the Gatt server.